# How to mix text-only RibbonToggleButton and image-only RibbonButton in Ribbon for WPF?

Tags: wpf, ribbon, togglebutton

I'm using the [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF October 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877) and have got 3 buttons next to each other, inside a `RibbonControlGroup`. The left and the right ones are text-only `RibbonToggleButton` controls, the one in the middle is an image-only `RibbonButton`. The buttons have a defined width to match the row above.

My code:

```xml
<r:RibbonControlGroup>
  <r:RibbonToggleButton Width="110" Label="Outgoing" IsChecked="True" />
  <!-- Padding and Height set to align the buttons/image -->
  <r:RibbonButton Width="30" Padding="5 0" Height="24" SmallImageSource="Images\Small\arrow_swap.png" />
  <r:RibbonToggleButton Width="110" Label="Incoming" />
</r:RibbonControlGroup>
```

The problem is that as soon as I apply the `SmallImageSource` to the middle button, the other two get spacings for images, causing the text not to be centered anymore. That is problem (1).

Because I didn't find a quick solution, I tried to add the image of the middle button not via `SmallImageSource`, but by adding it as `<Image>` for the content of the button. However, the button would remain empty. That is problem (2).

My third solution was to add images to the left and the right button, too. Unfortunately there is nearly no margin between the image and text, which looks quite ugly. I tried several things to enlarge the margin like adding a `<Style TargetType="Image">` to the `<RibbonToggleButton.Resources>`, but although the *editor* accepts it and displays the spacing at designtime, the margin is gone again at runtime. That is problem (3).

Does anybody have an appropiate solution to any of the three problems? I cannot get it to work. The number of the problems is also the preference of the alternatives, (1) being the most favourite to use with an appropiate hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you cannot do that. Its by design.

As per MSDN ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701790.aspx) about half way down the page):

> Related ribbon controls can be grouped together in a RibbonControlGroup. When a control group is resized, one RibbonControlSizeDefinition is applied to all of the controls in the RibbonControlGroup. The RibbonControlGroup is positioned in the RibbonGroup as if it were one control.

All the controls in a RibbonControlGroup shares the same RibbonControlSizeDefinition. Hence, in your case image will be added for all the buttons.

You may use RibbonGroup instead if you do not want to glue all your controls very closely. This way you can customize each button container by using different RibbonControlSizeDefinitions.

Comment: Judging by my experiences so far, WPF seemed to be a very well predefined framework for controls and concepts of UI design, where however you could override every default style with your own definitions. Wouldn't it be possible to define a custom RibbonControlSizeDefinition and to override the unified one for certain buttons?
Also, this doesn't explain why (2) doesn't work at all.

Comment: @LWChris no doubt WPF is matured, but RibbonControl still have many issues. You can override the default styles and templates, but sometimes these sort of things may take too much effort for too little gain.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you're right. I've always spent a lot of time to make the UI look perfectly like _I_ wanted it to look, but now I decided to add icons for my toggle buttons and cope with the no-spacing-between-icon-and-caption look.